# SQL Server 2008 column name 'Type' not shown in update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table called `Bowzer` which has a column called `Type`.

When I try to run this query, SSMS does not recognize the column `Type`.

Here is my query

```
update Bowzer
set inserted_by = ISNULL(inserted_by, 'Auto')
where (bowzer_id = 8 and inserted_by is null and type='CRUDE')
```

Here it does not recognize the column `Type` and gives an error

> Invalid Column Name Type

Is this column name `Type` not allowed?

Also, I want to check if the `Inserted_By` column is null then replace it with a value `Auto`

How do i do that?

**EDIT - 1 DDL To the Table Bowzer**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bowzer](
    [bowzer_id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [bowzer_no] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [quantity] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [dip1] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Cmpt_Capacity1] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [dip2] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Cmpt_Capacity2] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [dip3] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Cmpt_Capacity3] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [dip4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Cmpt_Capacity4] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [dip5] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Cmpt_Capacity5] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [expiry_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [status] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [inserted_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [inserted_by] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bowzer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [bowzer_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a column named `type` in `Bowzer`? Can you add the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) for Bowzer?

Comment: I assume you mean DropDownList by the term DDL. Yes i can do everything with this, its just the SSMS that wouldn't recognize this column name, the intellisense wont show it.

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language

Comment: Error "Invalid Column Name Type" or "intellisense wont show it". Which is it? Both?

Comment: First intellisense wont show it, but if i just type it, and place my mouse cursor over it, it gives this message 'Invalid Column Name Type'

Comment: Ok, then you don't have the column in the table and that is why IntelliSense does not show it. Type is an allowed field name as can be shown here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/799c2/1). Your query works just fine.

Comment: I do have that column in the table sir

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help you if you could add the DDL to your question. `create table Bowzer .....`

Comment: Please Check The Edits in my question

Comment: Using your table and your code you can see here that it works as expected. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb066/2

Comment: mikael yes the code works fine, my concern is "WHY INTELLISENSE ISN'T SHOWING THIS COLUMN'

Comment: Then you should update your question with that information. As it looks now you are getting an error message `Invalid Column Name Type` when executing your query. BTW, You accidentally pressed your caps-lock. My ears are still ringing :).

Comment: :) lets leave it now... Am done with the problem... Thanks buddy for your help ... accept my apologies for the ears part :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
update Bowzer
set inserted_by = ISNULL(inserted_by, 'Auto')
where (bowzer_id = 8 and inserted_by is null and [type]='CRUDE')
```

Comment: No, The intellisense doesn't recognize it either. It is showing Three Built-in Functions only. 1) TYPEPROPERTY (2) TYPE_ID (3) TYPE_NAME.... I think intellisense should also show the field name 'Type' , isn't it?

Comment: Why do you want the intellisense to show just run it. I accept it has to show, but won't stop you from running the query.

Comment: `type` is not a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in TSQL. You don't have to use a delimited identifier for `type`.

Answer (score 1):

for check if null,  use Case

```
Update Bowzer set inserted_by  = Case When inserted_by IS NULL THEN 'Auto' Else inserted_by End
where (bowzer_id = 8 and inserted_by is null and [type]='CRUDE')
```